# Generate matrix in Keras based on row and column

Tags: matrix, lambda, keras, layer

How I could create a layer in Keras that ouputs matrix given dimensions (e.g. m, n) with cells having a value based on the row and column?
Here is the forumula:

```
A[i, 2j] = i / (10**(2*j))
A[i, 2j+1] = i / (10**(2*j))
```

I tried to look on the lamba function but it seems Keras passed only the cell value and not the indices! Any other options (not a loop)

Comment: Would you clarify what do you mean by "matrix in Keras"? Is it supposed to be a layer that outputs a matrix? Then, what is its input?

Comment: it will be used as a layer and there no input just dimensions of the output later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from keras.layers import Input
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np


def CustomConstantInput(m, n):
    x = np.arange(m)
    y = 10 ** (2 * (np.arange(n) // 2))
    matrix = x[:, None] / y[None, :]
    print(matrix)
    fixed_input = K.constant(matrix)
    return Input(tensor=fixed_input)


t = CustomConstantInput(3, 4)
```